# Externally executable application fails for some application?

Tags: java, external, executable

I'm wanting to launch the program from a Java application, with some luck. Most programs are started without problems, but some seem to not execute properly(?).

The code I'm using is very simple:

```
private static void exec() {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\Fillipuster\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\Update.exe");

    try {
        builder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

...and works for almost all executables (*.exe). *Discord* is purposefully placed in the example, as it is one of the programs that cause this problem. (along with *Messenger For Windows* and *GOG Galaxy*).

The behavior is simple, and the same for all executable that causes this; a command prompt quickly pops into existence and then promptly disappears (pun intended) - resulting in the application not being launched.

Sifting through Google and Stack Overflow proved a futile effort, and at this point, I'm at a complete loss.

Any help/input is much appreciated.

Comment: i would assume that this is not ProcessBuilder at fault, but rather the programs in question refusing to run in the "fake" environment it provides.

Comment: Is (e.g. exception stack trace) anything printed in the command prompt window? Try pausing execution (sleep, wait for input, etc) after starting the process to see if there is any output

Comment: A great guess regarding the "fake" environment. Any remedy ideas?
@yoozer8: I tried to halt it with a sleep after starting the process to no avail.

Comment: I tried to replicate your example using the discord updater. For me executing it 1. manually, 2. via cmd, 3. via java did all have the same result. A terminal window appearing for half a second before it disappears again. Are you sure this isn't the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3244464/john), who pointed out that even launching the the *Update.exe* file "manually" results in the same behavior, I've found the problem.

It seems that when launching Discord successfully, one is actually launching a shortcut that gives a parameter to the executable. In this case:

```
--processStart Discord.exe
```

This means that the following code will in fact start Discord:

```
private static void exec() {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\Fillipuster\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\Update.exe", "--processStart", "Discord.exe");

    try {
        builder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks to John and all the other commenters.